# Compare Polars DataFrames That Have a Polars Date Colums

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-polars

I want to test that two Polars DataFame objects are equivalent, that contain a column which represents dates.

If I use `datetime.date` from the standard library I don't have any problems:

```py
import datetime as dt

import polars as pl
from polars.testing import assert_frame_equal

assert_frame_equal(pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1], "bar": [dt.date(2000, 1, 1)]}), pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1], "bar": [dt.date(2000, 1, 1)]}))
```

But if I try to use the `Date` type from polars the comparison fails, with a `PanicException: not implemented` exception.

```py
assert_frame_equal(pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1], "bar": [pl.Date(2000, 1, 1)]}), pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1], "bar": [pl.Date(2000, 1, 1)]}))
```

Is there a way to use the polars `Date` type in the `DataFrame` and still be able to compare the two objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're supposed to use `pl.Date` like that, otherwise your `DataFrame` is of dtype `object`, which is probably not what you wanted:

```
In [2]: pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1], "bar": [pl.Date(2000, 1, 1)]})
Out[2]:
shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ foo ┆ bar                                 │
│ --- ┆ ---                                 │
│ i64 ┆ object                              │
╞═════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ <polars.datatypes.Date object at... │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Instead, do:

```py
df1 = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1], "bar": ['2000-01-01']}).with_column(pl.col('bar').str.strptime(pl.Date))
df2 = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1], "bar": ['2000-01-01']}).with_column(pl.col('bar').str.strptime(pl.Date))

assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
```

and this works fine

Answer (score 1):

You should not put `pl.Date` in a `DataFrame`.

`pl.Date` is a `dtype` object and should not be used to instantiate values. The column type of the `DataFrame` also indicates that polars does not know what to do with it, as it inferred it as `object` dtype (read, I don't know what you gave me).

Using python's native `datetime, date, time, timedelta` are the way to go.

```py
import polars as pl
from polars.testing import assert_frame_equal
from datetime import date

assert_frame_equal(pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1], "bar": [date(2000, 1, 1)]}), 
                   pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1], "bar": [date(2000, 1, 1)]}))
```